# Otsu Thresholding OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv

I am performing change detection between 2 images using image ratioing and Otsu thresholding.
The last line of the code is giving error.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image1 = cv2.imread( 'E:\\alada.jpg',  0 )
image2 = cv2.imread( 'E:\\alada2.jpg', 0 )
dest   = 'E:\\Ratio\\'
print image1.shape

image1 = cv2.resize( image1, ( 300, 200 ) )
image2 = cv2.resize( image2, ( 300, 200 ) )
img1   = image1.ravel()
img2   = image2.ravel()
sd1    = np.std( img1 )
sd2    = np.std( img2 )
img2   = ( ( img2 - np.mean( img2 ) ) * sd1 / sd2 ) + np.mean( img1 )
ratio  = img1 / img2
ratio  = np.arctan(  ratio ) - np.pi / 4
ratio  = np.reshape( ratio, ( image1.shape[0], image1.shape[1] ) )
print ratio.shape

thresh, th2 = cv2.threshold( ratio, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU )


error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\thresh.cpp:718: error: (-215) 
src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function cv::threshold
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why?

**`cv2.threshold()`** expects the first argument ( <sub>a source image</sub>) to be a grayscale image.

### How?

In case you are not in a control of initial image production & pipeline processing, just convert the `[src]` before entering the `cv2.threshold()`

```
cv2.threshold( cv2.cvtColor( aSrcIMG, cv.CV_BGR2GRAY ), #<-ratio
               aThresholdVALUE,                         #<-    0
               aMaxVALUE,                               #<-  255
               aThresholdProcessTYPE                    #<-cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU
               )
```

Comment: The problem is that I am trying to threshold the array `ratio`,because that is what I want to do,but `cv2.threshold()` wants a grayscale image,like you mentioned.I am being incorrect in using `cv2.threshold()` this way

Comment: make it `np.array( ( 300, 200 ), dtype = np.int8 )` or run it through `cv2.convertScaleAbs( src )`

Comment: `cv2.convertScaleAbs(src)` worked.The idea was to make the datatype of `ratio` to np.int8,right? Because when openCV reads an image through `cv2.imread()`,the datatype is `np.uint8` also